# UIButton setTitleColor only works with Preset Component Values ios7?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I'm running into a strange thing here (iOS 7, Xcode 5):

If I use this code, the button title changes color:

```
[self.delayButton setTitleColor:[UIColor purpleColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

However, if I use this code, it just turns black:

```
[self.delayButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:128/255 green:0/255 blue:128/255 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

(FYI - this also turns black:)

```
UIColor *myColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:128/255 green:0/255 blue:128/255 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.delayButton setTitleColor:[UIColor myColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Basically, any color I create/use turns black *except* for the Preset Component Values like "redColor" "blueColor" etc....

Any ideas why?

Comment: Objective-C is based on C, and integer division *truncates* the result.

Comment: You're right - it is a duplicate - sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need use float values like this:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:128.f/255 green:0.f/255 blue:128.f/255 alpha:1.0];
```

In your code you use integer division: `128 / 255` results to `0`. That's why you see black color where values of RGB channels are zero.

Comment: FYI - the `.` in the number isn't needed. You can do `128f/255` or just do `128.0/255`.

Comment: It's been pointed out that this is a duplicate question - sorry. (Thanks for the response though!)

Comment: @rmaddy partially you are not right: `128f/255` doesn't compiled (at list by LLVM 5.1 that is used by Xcode).

Comment: Oops - my mistake. Sorry. Yes, it must be `127.f` or `127.0`.